# What is the difference between a Simple and Virtual Product?

Tags: configurable-product, simple-product, virtual-products

I am trying to upload a Product on our Magento 2 Back End. This is a ring and it has different variances.

I know I start with "Add Product" I complete all the other steps and underneath the Configurations Tab I click "Create Configurations" I then select Ring Sizes, I then select my Sizes, skip bulk price upload and Bulk Image upload and then in the 4th step I say Create Configurables.

After Saving my Product and then searching for it, I get the Mother Product (Configurable Product) and then all the different sizes - BUT the sizes come up as Virtual Products and comparing it to our other products, the different sizes should be simple products.

Can someone please help :|

Answer (score 1):

to answer the question....What is the difference between a Simple and Virtual Product?

A virtual product is something that cannot be shipped.  Something that does not have physical form.

Example:

- voucher codes
- access codes

A simple product is something that has for and requires shipping.

In magento, in case you only have virtual products in your cart, you will not be required to fill in a shipping address in the checkout process.

now in your case, your products should be simple and not virtual.  You can change that by filling in the weight attribute for your products.

[image]

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH!!!! @ma

Answer (score 1):

we don't need to define weight in virtual products

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem. but i want to solve it with an csv-import.

my qustion now is, how do i link the simple products with my configuratable product in the csv, i don't want magento to create one

thx for your advise!